# Google Map is not working with MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps

I have one fragment as below

```
public class WantToTrack extends Fragment {
// Code are here to set the view. 
//Layout name file is - want_to_track
 FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
 MapShowFragment f1 = new MapShowFragment();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.map, f1);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

My Layout file(want_to_track) is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/back_ground_clr"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/text_clr_for_back_ground"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/header_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="WANT TO TRACK" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/child_mail_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/text_clr_for_back_ground"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Email ID Whom you want to track" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sbmit_child_mail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
        android:background="@color/btn_login_bg"
        android:textColor="@color/btn_login"
        android:text="Go" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="126dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_below="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As by above mentioned code, I am trying to call dynamic fragment which will show Map. But map is not showing.My class

> MapShowFragment

is as below

```
public class MapShowFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    ArrayList<LatLng> MarkerPoints;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    List<Double> listOfLatitude,listOfLongitude;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup vg, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_show, vg, false);
        addItem();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
        // Initializing
        MarkerPoints = new ArrayList<>();

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapgoogle);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        return v;
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<listOfLongitude.size();i++){
            mapDraw(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Setting onclick event listener for the map
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
            }
        });

    }

    private String getUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;


        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;


        return url;
    }

    /**
     * A method to download json data from url
     */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();
            Log.d("downloadUrl", data.toString());
            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class FetchUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try {
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
                Log.d("Background Task data", data.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);

        }
    }

    /**
     * A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format
     */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                Log.d("ParserTask",jsonData[0].toString());
                DataParser parser = new DataParser();
                Log.d("ParserTask", parser.toString());

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
                Log.d("ParserTask","Executing routes");
                Log.d("ParserTask",routes.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("ParserTask",e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

            // Traversing through all the routes
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                points = new ArrayList<>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(10);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);

                Log.d("onPostExecute","onPostExecute lineoptions decoded");

            }

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            if(lineOptions != null) {
                mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
            }
            else {
                Log.d("onPostExecute","without Polylines drawn");
            }
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Asking user if explanation is needed
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted. Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
            // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
        }
    }

    void addItem(){
        listOfLatitude  = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfLongitude = new ArrayList<>();

        listOfLatitude.add(12.9177); // Silk Board
        listOfLatitude.add(12.9255); // Banshankri
        listOfLatitude.add(13.0350); // Nagwara

        listOfLongitude.add(77.6233);  // Silk Board
        listOfLongitude.add(77.5468);  // Banshankri
        listOfLongitude.add(77.6235);  // Nagwara
    }

    void mapDraw(int i){
        // Already two locations
        LatLng point = new LatLng(listOfLatitude.get(i), listOfLongitude.get(i));
/*        if (MarkerPoints.size() > 1) {
            MarkerPoints.clear();
            mMap.clear();
        }*/

        // Adding new item to the ArrayList
        MarkerPoints.add(point);

        // Creating MarkerOptions
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

        // Setting the position of the marker
        options.position(point);

        /**
         * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
         * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
         */
        if (MarkerPoints.size() == 1) {
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
        } else if (MarkerPoints.size() == 2) {
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
        }else if (MarkerPoints.size() == 3) {
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
        }


        // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
        mMap.addMarker(options);

        // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
        if (MarkerPoints.size() >= 2) {
            if(MarkerPoints.size()<=i+1) {
                LatLng origin = MarkerPoints.get(i-1);
                LatLng dest = MarkerPoints.get(i);

                // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                String url = getUrl(origin, dest);
                Log.d("onMapClick", url.toString());
                FetchUrl FetchUrl = new FetchUrl();

                // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                FetchUrl.execute(url);
                //move map camera
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(origin));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even i have used correct API key which is generated from Google console. In below image map should come on red rectangle but its not populating.

[image]

I tried to track my issue through Log-cat but i am not able to find any trace which could help me.

Comment: have you tried with layout_height as fixed?

Comment: Yes.. Tried with it.. Not working...

Comment: directly use fragment instead of framelayout with width and height as `match_parent`

Comment: Have u enabled the map sdk in the google developers console ?